# is there a way to generate an rss feed for a site created with reacjs?

Tags: reactjs, web, notifications, rss

I have a site created in reactjs, and I would like to notify my users when I add a post to the site via automated RSS. is there any way to do it? thanks

Comment: That you use ReactJS for the frontend is very likely to be completely incidental to how you generate RSS.

Comment: Did you able to achieve this?